# Save SQLite TIMESTAMP in the format of MySQL TIMESTAMP, Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to save current TIMESTAMP to a SQLite database in Android.

But it should be in MySQL TIMESTAMP format which is `2014-04-02 20:04:05`

How to make it in `db.execSQL();`

Please help!

Comment: what is the current format?

Comment: The two formats should simply be the same. If not, the SQlite database shouldn't accept it

Comment: @weeknie Actually I'm not going to save MySQL TIMESTAMP, but I need to save current TIMESTAMP in the form of MySQL

Comment: @HamidShatu There are many formats. I need it in 2014-04-02 20:04:05 format

Comment: @eMM...current TIMESTAMP is `String` or `Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SQLite date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html). You would do something like
`strftime(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S, 'now')` in your SQL string. This particular format also has a shortcut: `datetime('now')`

```
db.execSql("insert into table (column) values ( datetime('now') )");
```

My preference though is to simply store the current time as a long, which you can then format any way you like (or any way the user likes, or any way the system defaults to showing dates/times).

Comment: How would I do it this way please                                      db.execSql("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_TODO + "("+KEY_CREATED_AT + " DATETIME" +")");

Comment: Ah, that's a different question. Somethign you need to know about SQLite is that it really only has 5 column types: INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB, and NULL. It may recognize other type names like varchar, but it translates that to a type it knows: TEXT. From the SQLite documentation: "SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values"

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following date format in order to insert dates/times in SQLite:

```
DateFormat dateFormatISO8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

and retrieve in string as below:

```
String crntDate = dateFormatISO8601.format(new Date());
```

P.S. Make sure your column is of type DATETIME

Comment: how to create the table with a DATETIME column in the format of yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss please?

Comment: create table tbl1(id int primary key, dt datetime);

Comment: Then I have to insert crnDate for the column dt isn't it?